# does as3 require the flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I am helping to build a video based website.  My client wants the website to be viewable on ipads/iphones.  Therefore, I absolutely can not require the flash viewer.

One of my developers wants to use AS3 for scripting special features in our player.   If AS3 scripting is used, does that mean my users must have the flash plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: if your developer has any idea what AS3 means than he should know that publishing for the web requires flash player. I suggest you use HTML5 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about playing videos, then html5 based option would be great. But if the requirement is more complicated and the developer is more comfortable with AS3, then you can have an AIR app re-packaged as iOS app (that's a supported workflow from Adobe).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the users would have to have the Flash Player installed to view an AS3 flash file (.swf).

But your developers might implement an html5 alternative of the video player for iOS that doesn't require flash (which probably will be missing some of those special features) so the website might still be viewable on iOS devices.

My advice would be to simply ask them if it will work on iPad and iPhone :-)